# jQuery scrolling doesn't do as supposed

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I know that this topic is all over this site but I could not find anything specific for my problem.

The thing is I want to scroll slowly to divs. It works fine until the second click, or when scrolled anywhere in the page, except at the top. I need the specified div element to be at the very top of the screen, when navigation is clicked. My jQuery lines:

```
$("#vitals").click(function(){
    $(".parallax").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#toVitals").offset().top},
        'slow');
});

$("#andrejs").click(function(){
    $(".parallax").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#toAndrejs").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

my navigation bar:

```
<nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="firstLiElement" class="main-nav ieraksti"><a href="prew2.html">ieraksti!</a></li>
                <ul id="audio_sub_menu">
                    <li id="vitals"><a href="prew2.html#toAudio">audio</a></li>
                    <li id="andrejs"><a href="prew2.html#toVideo">video</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li class="main-nav" id="audio"><a href="prew3.html">paklausies!</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav" id="video"><a href="prew4.html">paskaties!</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav"><a href="prew8.html">latvian voice-overs</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav" id="kontakti"><a href="prew5.html">pasūti!</a></li>
                <li class="sejputns"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Ierakstilv/1631345117081018" target="_blank"><img src="sejbuksis.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Those divs are located in a div with class "parallax", and they do not scroll at all, if I use

```
$('html, body').animate...
```

My page structure is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navigation" style="margin-top: -20px;">
        <div id="logo" style="margin-top: 15px;"></div>
            <nav></nav>     
        </div>

        <div class="parallax">
            <div id="firstBack" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back"></div>
            <div id="secondBack" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back" style="margin-top: 145.08px; z-index: 1;"></div>
            <div id="thirdBack" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back" style="margin-top: 604.5px; z-index: -1;"></div>
            <div id="overBox" style="margin-top: 100.75px;"></div>
            <div id="info" class="parallax__layer--base" style="margin-top: 241.8px;"></div>
            <div id="info2" class="parallax__layer--base" style="margin-top: 290.16px;"></div>
            <div id="info3" class="parallax__layer--base" style="margin-top: 322.4px;"></div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the needed divs are located one at info2 and one at info3 div.
So what happens is I click the `<li id="vitals">audio</li>` and it goes to the right spot, but only if I was at the top of the page. If I click again, it scroll to the top. And the worst thing is that if I click the first and then the second, it doesn't even find the second div.
Any ideas why? I'm open to anything.

Comment: Only <li> can go inside <ul>. You should put the <a> anchor inside the <li>. Like this <ul><li><a>hello</a></li><li><a>hello 2</a></li></ul>

Comment: Alright, I will keep that in mind, but would it really solve my problem?

Comment: You can't work with broken html you will get unpredictable results. Fix it and then correct your question if you still have a problem :)

Comment: @VisualMicro Done what you suggested, now I have only <li> tags inside of the <ul>, but that still doesnt solve my problem, I am 99% sure, that there is some kind of jQuery specific problem that I do not know, which prevents the page from scrolling correctly, because as I said, when the page is scrolled at the top, it works as a charm, but problems start when I have scrolled to anywhere else...

Comment: @VisualStudio I still cannot find the solution to this problem, it has been cracking my head for days. Did you have any other solutions?

Comment: Just to add a log/trace element to the screen and output some useful values so you can see what is going on